# How can I output a string with it's newline characters visible in php?

Tags: php, string, echo

I have a string with newlines that I'd like to print out so that I see the special chars (such as `\n`) rather than the newlines themselves.

So a string that would typically be `echo`'d as

```
this is the top line of my string
this is the second line of the string
```

Would instead look like this:

```
this is the top line of my string\nthis is the second line of the string
```

How could I accomplish this in php?

Comment: `addslashes()` or replace \n with \\n.

Comment: Hmm... strangely `addslashes()` didn't work for me, but it seems to be what I was after. Using addslashes() is still giving me a string where it appears on multiple lines.

Comment: @johncorser What is the **exact** output from: `var_dump($yourString);` taken from the source code?

Comment: The exact var_dump is this: http://jpst.it/A8M2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$string = "this is the top line of my string
this is the second line of the string";

echo json_encode($string);

?>
```

Comment: This worked for what I needed it for. Good thinking!

Comment: Always try to keep it clean and simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [addcslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) function:

```
string addcslashes ( string $str , string $charlist )
```

which will return a string with backslashes before characters.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is

```
echo str_replace("\n", '\n', $yourstring);
```

Of course, there are many other ways and you can assign instead of echoing, and enhance your code so on.

Consider that new lines might be treated differently according to the underlaying operating system.

> also consider reading the theorical background about [new line and carrier return](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)